# Container, Row, Col - in React-Bootstrap not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm currently attempting to learn React, and React-Bootstrap.

I'm attempting to make good use of the React-Bootstrap grid layout. I'm not sure if I'm implementing it incorrectly. My gut says I'm using an impropver version somewhere because as far as I can tell the "Container, Col, Row" functionality isn't working at all.

What could be the issue? I'm out of ideas.

Versions from package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "typescript": "^3.3.4000"
```

The package.json from "bootstrap" dir:

```
  "_from": "bootstrap@latest",
  "_id": "bootstrap@4.3.1",
```

The package.json from "react-bootstrap" dir:

```
  "_from": "react-bootstrap@^1.0.0-beta.6",
  "_id": "react-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6",
```

Please note that I've also tried installing and using `bootstrap@3` with no luck:

`npm install bootstrap@3 --save`
`npm i --save bootstrap@3`

Major snippet from index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

class Module extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
  }

  clickHandler = (command) =>
  {
    // ... some handler code here
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th class="r1_header"> Header 1 </th>
                <th class="r1_header"> Header 2 </th>
                <th class="r1_header"> Header 3 </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> <button/> </td> // some more button stuff here
                <td> <button/> </td>
                <td> <button/> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> <button/> </td>
                <td> <button/> </td>
                <td> <button/> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> <button/> </td>
                <td> <button/> </td> 
                <td> <button/> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="r2_header"> Header 1 </th>
                <th class="r2_header"> Header 2 </th>
                <th class="r2_header"> Header 3 </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> <button/> </td>
                <td> <button/> </td>
                <td> <button/> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> <button/> </td>
                <td> <button/> </td>
                <td> <button/> </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> <button/> </td>
                <td> <button/> </td>
                <td> <button/> </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            // another table here... should be aligned next to the
            // prev "col" horizontally but is going underneath (vertically)
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

Here is an MCVE...

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n76nvwy18m?fontsize=14)

The displayed text should be `HelloWorld` but instead its:

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here or what the expected behaviour should be. Why do you have a `table` within a `Col`?

Comment: I’m attempting to put a block of text next to the table horizontally.

Comment: So the table would be in the first column of the row and some data in the next.

Comment: Could you create an [MCVE (Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in codesandbox or similar?

Comment: @Pineda I've edited my post with the MCVE.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. It was a miss-step on my part. I missed a crucial part of the set up outlined on the react-bootstrap main regarding [style sheets](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets).

In `index.html` copy and paste the path to the latest bootstrap style sheets:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

Comment: Wow! What a simple but dumb mistake on my part!

Comment: Don't forget to get the latest version of this link here:

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

Comment: another life saver

Comment: Very helpful your answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 26):

According to react documentation you have to install bootstrap first

> npm Install react-bootstrap bootstrap

then you have to import this line in your index.js or App.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

then you can import like this in your components `import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';`
and use like this

```
 <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>1</Col>
                    <Col>2</Col>
                    <Col>3</Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use grid and then specify the no of columns you want to give for table and no of columns you want to keep for other stuff out of 12.
like in below code.

import Grid, Row and cols like

```
import { Row, Col, Grid } from 'react-bootstrap';



<Grid>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md="6">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="r1_header"> Header 1 </th>
                                    <th class="r1_header"> Header 2 </th>
                                    <th class="r1_header"> Header 3 </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <button /> </td> // some more button stuff here
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="r2_header"> Header 1 </th>
                                    <th class="r2_header"> Header 2 </th>
                                    <th class="r2_header"> Header 3 </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                    <td> <button /> </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="6">
                            {"dsfdsdsf"}
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for input. Unfortunately it doesn't seem like Grid is supported in the version I'm using. I tried to specify the column length for containers and that didn't help either.

Comment: Grid has been renamed to Container. check https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/migrating/

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`
 in the index.js file. Make sure to `npm install bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. i search a lot then i fixed my problem.

I am assuming that you have install `react-bootstrap bootstrap` library.

by `npm instll react-bootstrap bootstrap`. so the next step is to add the Bootstrap file in `index.js` or `app.js`. in my case I added `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` in `index.js`.

Now time to import the **Component** that i am using. I am using components into `App.js`

```
import { Image ,Button  ,Row ,Col } from "react-bootstrap";
```

i am using **Image ,Button , Row , Col** .

my real code is

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Image ,Button  ,Row ,Col } from "react-bootstrap";


function App() {
  let authorName ="Pankaj Kumar";


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span className="badge bg-danger">React JS component</span> <br />
      <Image
          src="https://dummyimage.com/170x180/000/fff.png&text=TEST123"
          thumbnail
        />

      <Row className="mx-0">
        <Button as={Col} variant="primary">Button #1</Button>
        <Button as={Col} variant="secondary" className="mx-2">Button #2</Button>
        <Button as={Col} variant="success">Button #3</Button>
      </Row>

    </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Output :

[image]

For more details: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-import-components-from-react-bootstrap

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved the issue. It was a miss-step on my part. I missed a crucial part of the set up outlined on the react-bootstrap main regarding style sheets.

In index.html copy and paste the path to the latest bootstrap style sheets:`

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

`

Comment: Don't just copy paste others answers.